# probability and post-measurement state with observable ⊗

Tags: probability

Today I learned about these but I can't know how to solve this probem.

$|⟩={\frac1 {√3}}(|01⟩+|10⟩+|11⟩) $

I want to measure observable  ⊗ . What is the probability of measuring  |+⟩  on the second qubit and the post-measurement state  for the first qubit?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics#Generalized_measurement_(POVM)) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have an observable $I\otimes X$. This has eigenvalues $\pm 1$. The $+1$ eigenvalues correspond to the second qubit being in the $|+\rangle$ state. So, the projectors for the measurement are
$$
P_{\pm}=(I\otimes I\pm I\otimes X)/2.
$$
With the projectors, you can use the usual measurement formalism: the probability of getting the $+1$ result is
$$
p+=\langle\psi|P_+|\psi\rangle
$$
and the state after measurement is
$$
P_+|\psi\rangle/\sqrt{p_+}.
$$

I leave you to do the actual calculation...